# Smalltalk Windows application works in debug mode; .exe hangs

Tags: windows, smalltalk

I am working with a Windows application developed in Smalltalk 3.1, and here's something really weird that I just found and I'm not sure how many detail I should include, so I'll try to start a conversation with the main scenario:

The program opens a project from a remote machine, which makes the interface hang for a long time (~10 minutes) before it becomes responsive again.

Now, if I launch the program from within Smalltalk and add a `self halt.` just anywhere near the relevant operations that deal with opening a project, the issue does not happen. Now, if I don't add any halts and launch it from Smalltalk then the problem shows up again.

I wonder if this is something common in Smalltalk apps, since I don't know much about the language.

Comment: Are you running these "tests" from the same development image? Also, if you add the `halt` and then remove it, does the problem persist?

Comment: What "Smalltalk" are you referring to? Squeak, Pharo, Dolphin, VisualWorks, VisualAge...? And how to you launch the program? Do you click on some button or do you evaluate code? In the latter case you could try running the code forked at a lower priority (Squeak/Pharo dialect): `[ <launch code> ] forkAt: Processor userBackgroundPriority`. If the "unresponsiveness" is due to something blocking the UI process then this should help.

Comment: Yes all tests are in the same dev image,and  the problem comes back if I add the `halt` and then remove it. It's one of the Visual SmallTalks, not sure which one really! Doesn't look like VisualWorks though... 

`RqReqBrowserDlg reinitializeChoices.    "mpwAdded"
self halt.
    App explorerPane initItems; redisplay.`

That's the part of the code where the magic happens. The interface elements show up after `initItems` evaluates and then hangs -not so with that halt in there.

Comment: By the way, do you know what happens if I compile the application with that `halt` in there?

Comment: Packaging a runtime image with a halt in it will result in the program writing a walkback.log file either onto stderr or a file and the program terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a timing issue to me.

When you add the `self halt` your program will wait for you to press the "resume button", thereby adding a delay prior to the `App explorerPane initItems; redisplay` code

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the end I wasn't able to solve the mystery but did solve the original issue with the application.